# How to use drupal function in simple php file inner drupal?

Tags: theming

I want to use $user and db_query in  credit.php file. This file exist inner theme file.. here $user and db_query is not working. How to make any simple .php file to drupal file.

I am using this code but it produces an error:

```
/** bootstrap Drupal **/
chdir("/path/to/drupal/site/htdocs");
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Unfortunately, I am unable to understand what you're asking.  Making the question clearer will increase your chances of getting an answer.  You may ask about how to create a custom PHP module for Drupal - but it is far from certain.

Comment: To add to what @FreeRadical said, it's not clear what you mean by "in inner Drupal."

Comment: I want to use drupal query and some function like global $user in simple .php file . inner module file.

Comment: @jhs, writing PHP for Drupal using global variables and calling API functions such as [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) is not different from writing PHP for anything else (and as a Drupal developer, I've no idea what a ".inner module" or "inner theme file" is). And if you want help with your code, you *must* post the code.

Comment: I am using this code but its getting me error:/** bootstrap Drupal **/
chdir("/path/to/drupal/site/htdocs");
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

Comment: I nominated this question for reopening. If I understand correctly, @jsh wants to add a custom php file to a drupal site, and be able to use the global $user variable and the db_query function. The answer to this question should probably include creating a custom module and the Drupal hook system.